# Where do I find app.config file in .NET framework 4.0?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, app-config

**Where do I find app.config file in .NET framework 4.0 ?**
To be more elaborative I need that file to edit it, but not able to find the destination of the file.. 
Please tell me where can I search it for ASAP.
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App.config is named after the application, e.g. if YourApplication.exe has a YourApplication.exe.config then this will be used. (The file is only called app.config in Visual Studio and renamed on build)

Comment: Thank you man, it was of great help, needed it urgently...
#Great-full.